# Android : SEND_SMS Permission not listed for tablet

Tags: android, sms, manifest, tablet, telephony

I published my app on google play, my application is on phone and tablet, the application uses the sending of SMS functionality, in case we're on the phone and sending email if we amount of shelf off when publishing my app on google play, the app is not downloaded from a tablet
PS: sorry for my english

Here is my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.package.myapps"
android:versionCode="10"
android:versionName="1.107" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />


<compatible-screens>
 <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
 <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
 <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />

 <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
 <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640" />
 <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="640" />

<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" /> 
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" /> 
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" /> 
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

<!--all normal size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

<!-- all large size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

<!-- all xlarge size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />



<!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens 
          android:smallScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:xlargeScreens="true"
          android:resizeable="true" 
          android:anyDensity="true"/>


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.TELEPHONY" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.GPS" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" android:required="false"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false" />

 <permission
    android:name="com.package.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" /> 

 <uses-permission android:name="com.package.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Please clarify. What is your question? it is really hard to tell what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit old, but maybe someone will find the answer useful.

1. There are two different declarations `uses-permission` and `uses-feature`. They have different set of attributes and different permission/feature names.
2. There is no `android:required` attribute for `uses-permission` declaration, so it will be ignored if specified.
3. The `uses-feature` declaration has `android:required` attribute and you can set it to `false` to disable filtering on this particular feature.
4. Google Play will automatically detect required device hardware features from `uses-permission` declaration and filter search results based on both - them and `uses-feature` declarations. More about implicit filtering is in the Google documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#implicit).
5. The `uses-feature` declaration has a precedence over `uses-permission` declaration when we speak about filtering.

Mistake in the manifest from the question is incorrect feature declaration. It is case sensitive in Android and should be

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

instead of

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.TELEPHONY" android:required="false"/>
```

Application will no longer be filtered after this fix. And you can remove `android:required="false"` from all permission declarations to make manifest clean:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

List of permissions that imply hardware features with their names could also be found in the Google documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#permissions-features)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from your question is you're wondering why when you go to install your newly added app to the Google Play Store on a tablet, it doesn't say that the app uses this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="false" />
```

This is due to the fact that tablets cannot send SMS text messages, only mobile phones can and therefore it ignores this permission when the user accesses your app store page on a tablet device.

One of your permissions will not be applicable for tablets and therefore Google won't display it. Please note it shouldn't be one where the 'android:required' is set to false. It would be worth checking the others individually though.

Comment: yes, actually I agree with you, but my application needs sms-sending functions in case you are on the phone
In the code I check if we are on a phone I use sending SMS functions, otherwise if we are on a tablette is sending an email

Comment: So if I understand well, it is not possible to have SEND_SMS functionality and the application visible on tablet? even if the function is only used on phones

Comment: I am not sure it is just that. It is almost definitely to do with your permissions in some way though. Try removing it and reloading to the store to see!

Comment: I tried to remove the permission, but suddenly necessarily the sending SMS does not work on smartphones, suddenly this solution is not good

Comment: I know. You will have to comment out the code that utilises SMS on mobiles. It's just a test! I think the issue is actually a permission that is required...not one where you have put the flag as required=false such as Send SMS.